# Let Excel Solver Operate with Natural Numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My workbook is a bit complicated, but the basic problem can be illustrated with a short example.

Let's assume that I have 5 cells in Excel: A, B, C, D, and E.

```
A = 0
B = 5 * A 
C = 0 
D = 10 * C
E = B + D
```

In the Excel Solver Function I select cell E as the objective that is to be maximised, and cells A and C as the variable cells. Furthermore, I add the constraint that cell E must not exceed 10, and the second constraint that cells A and C must be integers.

The ideal solution would be that the value in cell A should be 0, and the value in cell C should be 10. In the more complicated version of this problem, however, Excel cannot find the optional solution.

The way the current formulas look like I expect that Excel could find the right solution, if excel only used natural numbers to find the optimal solution. For example, Excel currently would look at the outcome for A = 0.01 and C = 9.99. Instead, Excel should strictly compare outcomes for variable choices such as A = 1 and C = 9.

How can I make the Excel solver function operate with natural numbers only?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you keep your current cells, and create a mirror set beside them. Each mirror cell will equal the rounded version of the original cell. ie: RoundedA will have the formula:

```
=ROUND(A,0)
```

Then when you do your data analysis, solve for the rounded version of those cells, with the changing variable being one of the "original" cells.

**EDIT**
As discussed below, you may need to 'trick' data validation into creating the values you want.

Assume A1 is going to be your "testing" data validation cell. B1 is a permanently blank cell. Set another cell, say, C1, equal to:

```
=randbetween(1,10)
```

This will create a random integer between 1 and 10. Set your "variable" cell to be equal to C10. So, your variable cell will always be a random number between 1 & 10 (or you could set "1" equal to the smallest number of your other variables, and "10" equal to the largest number of your other variables. This will create the scope needed to answer your question).

Then when you do data validation, make it try to get A1 = TRUE. Do this by figuring out what the 'test' condition is of your cells. Something like "when X = 0, I know that all my variables are correct". ie set A1 to:

```
=if(X=0,1,0)
```

Then do data validation by changing B1 (your blank, unrefered-to cell), waiting until A1 = 1. Does that make sense? It will turn C1 into the random cycling variable between LOWVALUE and HIGHVALUE, always using integers. Data validation will stop when A1 = 1 (which happens when some value X = 0). B1 will just spin uselessly until Data validation finds something (or it will stop after a few hundred tries if it finds nothing).

Comment: Good idea! Implemented that right away. The next problem then becomes, however, that the solver function stops optimising and keeps all the values at "0", thinking this is optimal since all the choices from 0.0000001 to 0.4999999 are rounded to 0 and appear to yield no improvement. What settings for the solver function would avoid that behavior?

Comment: @TimoKrall There are a couple of ways you could solve this that might work. Data validation works based on "what appears to be working", and as you indicate may increment too-slowly to actually find an accurate value if we are rounding results. Try either: (1) putting in a "close" approximation manually before running. This will give it an indication of the magnitude of number required to solve. (2) you can 'trick' data validation, by making it uselessly run in the background while a random number generator cycles through. I will edit in an example of that in my response.

Comment: Interesting method. Unfortunately, the randbetween(0,3) method does not work, because the sensible values vary only between 0 and 3 for each of the 21 cells. The constraint, however, is that the total sum of values must not exceed 6. The probability that 21 values are randomly drawn so that 6 is not exceeded, however, is very small. Therefore, most randomly compared values fail to satisfy the constraint let alone are optimal.

Comment: @TimoKrall I occassionally use this method when I am doing desparation-level problem solving to find combinations of numbers which add together to form 0. If there are many possible scenarios, go to the Excel FILE button, go OPTIONS - > Formulas ->Enable 100 iterations, and change 100 iterations to 32000 (or whatever the max is). This will keep spinning for quite a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

To get Solver to try larger increment **divide the target cells by a large number** and in such a way, each increment that solver tries is larger. (for example it changes the target cells by +-0.00001 - in that case divide the target cells by 100000 or more).

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM0kU.png)
When adding the constraints, choose the int sign for the variables you want to be in natural nums.